# Input removing leading 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, input-mask

I have a form input field.

```
<input style="text-align:right;" type="text" name="DiversionCalc_Diversion_Rate" id="calc_dr" value="0.25%" />
```

I am attempting to format it based on focusout using jQuery 1.7.2

```
$('#calc_dr').focusout(function () {
    var value = $.trim($(this).val()).toString();
    if (value.indexOf("0.") === -1) {
        var $t = ("0" + value).toString();
        alert($t);
        $(this).val($t);
    }
    if (value != '' && value.indexOf("%") === -1) {
        $(this).val(value + '%');
    }
});
```

While this mostly is working, the alert pops up the correct 0.25 when I enter .25 in the field, however, the `$(this).val` only ever shows .25

How can I get it to show what it's showing me in the alert???

Comment: because you're still using `value`. You have to make `$t` global and assign that.

Comment: Your second if block is replacing it back to the original value. Test with ".25%"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `$t` a global variable (pull it out of the if loop) and assign it instead of `value`.

```
$('#calc_dr').focusout(function () {
    var value = $.trim($(this).val()).toString();
    var $t = value;
    if (value.indexOf("0.") === -1) {
        $t = ("0" + value).toString();
        alert($t);
        $(this).val($t);
    }
    if ($t != '' && $t.indexOf("%") === -1) {
        $(this).val($t + '%');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to grab the value, manipulate the value, then update the UI. The key being there is only one update at the end.

```
// Get the new value (strip everything but numbers and period)
var v= parseFloat($(this).val().toString().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));

// Basic data type validation
if (isNaN(v)) v= 0;
if (v< 0) v= 0;
if (v> 100) v= 100;

// other validation updates v as needed...
doCheckDiversionRate(v);

// update UI (btw toFixed() will add a leading zero)
$(this).val(v.toFixed(2) + '%');
```